# How can I hide an option of a select by it's text value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code in my dropdown list:

```
<select id="state_code" name="account[state_code]">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="AE">Armed Forces</option>
    <option value="AA">Armed Forces</option>
    <option value="AP">Armed Forces</option>
    <option value="AS">translation missing: en.world.us.as.name</option>
    <option value="DC">translation missing: en.world.us.dc.name</option>
    <option value="GU">translation missing: en.world.us.gu.name</option>
    <option value="MP">translation missing: en.world.us.mp.name</option>
    <option value="PR">translation missing: en.world.us.pr.name</option>
    <option value="UM">translation missing: en.world.us.um.name</option>
    <option value="VI">translation missing: en.world.us.vi.name</option>
</select>
```

I want hide all options whose text starts with `translation missing: en.world.us`. I have tried the below, but its not working.

```
var ab = "translation missing: en.world"
$('#state_code').find('option[text^="' + ab + '"]').hide();
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text of an element is not an attribute, so the attribute selector will not work in thise case, as you've discovered. Instead you can use a combination of a regular expression and the `filter()` function to achieve this:

```
$('#state_code option').filter(function() {
    return /^translation missing:/i.test($(this).text());
}).hide();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLetebkc/)

> I want to hide now both **translation missing: en.world.us** and **Armed Forces**

For this you can use the 'or' character in regex: `|`. What you tried won't work as the logic flow is flawed due to two `return` statements. Try this:

```
$('#state_code option').filter(function() {
    return /^translation missing:|armed forces/i.test($(this).text());
}).hide();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLetebkc/1/)

Comment: I want to hide now both  **translation missing: en.world.us** and **Armed Forces** so for this I had written    `$('#state_code option').filter(function() { 
     return /^translation missing:/i.test($(this).text()); 
     return /^Armed Forces /i.test($(this).text()); }).hide();` but its not working

Answer (score 1):

`text` is not an attribute, `HTMLOptionElement` object has `text` *property*. You can use the `filter` and `String.prototype.indexOf` method for filtering the matching options.

```
$('#state_code').children().filter(function() {
    return this.text.indexOf(ab) === 0;
}).hide();
```